# Update Form with Django from GET value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a function which let to handle forms updating.
In my view, user gives an ID, then the script takes this ID and display the corresponding form with the possibility to update data.

**My function looks like :**

```
def Identity_Update(request) :

    query_update = request.GET.get('q4')
    if query_update :
        query_update_list = Identity.objects.filter(id__iexact=query_update)    
    else :
        query_update_list = Identity.objects.none() # == []

    template_name = 'edit.html'

    ############

    instance = Identity.objects.get(id = ??? ) # ID have to be egal to query_update
    form = IdentityForm(request.POST or None, instance = instance)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('accueil')

    context = {
        "query_update" : query_update,
        "query_update_list" : query_update_list,
        "form": form,
        "instance" : instance
        }

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**My template looks like :**

```
<!-- ############################################## -->
<!-- Modifier un formulaire dans la Base de Données -->
<!-- ############################################## -->

<h2 align="center"> Modification des fiches individuelles </align> </h2>

{% block content %}

<h4> ID du formulaire à modifier : </h4>

<form method="GET" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text"  name="q4" placeholder="Entrer un ID" value="{{ request.GET.q4 }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Valider l'ID">
</form>

<ul>
    Personne concernée : 
    <br></br>
{% for item in query_update_list %}
   <li> {{ item }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<br></br>

<h4> Modification du formulaire : </h4>

<form method='POST' action= "" > {% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_ul}}

<input type ="submit" value="Valider" /> 
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I get the following problem :

How I could take the value `q4` returned by user and place it as `id = q4`.
I don't find a way to make that.
In the picture, the form is already filled because I wrote manually an id, but the form should stay empty until I give a value to `q4`

Thank you very much if you can help me !

[image]

PS : Maybe I need to put the form part inside `query_update if loop` ?

Comment: What exactly problems do you have? Do you have any error message?

Comment: It would be much easier to use the existing `UpdateView`..

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I cannot display the associated form with ID given by user and modify it

Comment: @Sayse I didn't know this existing `UpdateView`. I will read more informations about this function

Comment: Thank you for -1 each time I ask questions ... I'm beginning with Django, even if I read the documentation, I have lots of questions ... So thank you to put -1 without comment .. Furthermore, questions are well written to my mind.

Comment: Please spend time researching your own problem before asking questions, copying your title into google produces multiple duplicates

Comment: @Sayse I spent long time before asking questions .. If I'm asking question, it's because I don't find good example to my case :/

Comment: Then include that research in your question, [ask] contains more helpful advice

Comment: I added an edited part based on Stackoverflow example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override get_object() method of IdentityUpdate class to select specific object from request's GET parameters.

```
class IdentityUpdate(UpdateView) :

    model = Identity
    form_class = IdentityForm
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'resume.html'

    def get_object(self):
        query_update = request.GET.get('q4')
        return get_object_or_404(Identity, pk=query_update)
```

If you prefer to work with function based view try to change Identity_Update() view to this:

```
def Identity_Update(request) :

    # ID object given by user
    query_update = request.GET.get('q4')
    obj = get_object_or_404(Identity, pk=query_update)

    if query_update : 
        updating_form = IdentityForm(request.POST, instance = obj)
    ....
```

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to work with function based view. It's more or less what I've done previously. I will make some try in order to modify objects from database

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of you is :

when you post this form:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

the value in your `q4` input will not be submit cause they are in different form, so you can'd get the `q4`(ID?) value in your view. So I suggest you should post then on the same form.

Comment: I reorganize my question with more examples. I'm just blocking on one point : associate `id` with `q4` user value